# Javascript alert in C# not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have few textboxes to view and also update records. Here is my code to check for any duplicate record before save or update & alert the user if there is any. 
The javascript alert is popping up for 'Update' but not for 'Save'. The debugger even reads the line in the else block. Where am I going wrong?

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int returnId;
    returnId = chkDuplicates(value,1);//function to check for any duplicate value
    if(returnId==0)
      //save the record
    else
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,typeof(Page), "MsgSave", 
                                         "alert('value exists');", true);
 }

  protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int returnId;
    returnId = chkDuplicates(value,2);//function to check for any duplicate value
    if(returnId==0)
      //update the record
    else
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,typeof(Page), "MsgUpdate", 
                                         "alert('value exists');", true);
 }
```

Comment: are you redirecting to some other page after `save` button?

Comment: so on clicking `save` no redirection takes place right?

Comment: Yes That is right. No redirection.

Comment: once check the `returnId` value returned on clicking `save` button.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, It may helps

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(),
     "Msg", "alert('value exists');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that the function chkDuplicates actually returns a non zero value for the Save_Click use case?

Any ways this is not the appropriate way to implement such use cases. The best way would be to create these methods as Webmethods and call them via ajax calls on button click events using javascript. Throw a custom exception in case the duplicate exists. This will result in the faliure callback on your ajax call. On this call back show watever alert you need to show.

This is how you do it elegantly and not register scripts in server side code. This will also save your application from post backs and unnecessary page reloads.

Comment: Agreed that this is not an elegant way, but a novice here. The value returned is 1 and it also reads the 'scriptmanager....' line in the else block. I wonder, why the same thing can work when I click Update but not on Save

Comment: You use the same name to register your scripts that is what the problem is as I believe.. try with a different name then.

Comment: And if you want help with implementing it the good way.. check this http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 1):

In both of your Startup Scripts, your Key is

> "Msg"

and If you look for the definition of 'string key' parameter in RegisterStartupScript Method, it says '*A Unique Identifier for the Script Block*'. So it must be Unique from other Keys in the specific Page.

Comment: Makes Sense. I changed the parameter. But prblem persists. Pops up only for update

Comment: and you already make sure it that your code is executing correctly (i.e Debugger comes in the Save_Click method) when you click to save??

Answer (score 0):

On the button, add an onClientClick to call the JavaScript. If it then passes you're, server side code will be called.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand. The fn. checks for values in DB and gets back with 0 or 1. And also, I can see the alert fine in Update click, though it doesnt have an onclientclick.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way for showing javascript alert popup could be this

```
Response.Write("<script>alert(\"Your text here\");</script>");
```

Comment: try passing "MsgSave" as your 3rd parameter instead of "Msg" in your ScriptManager function call in Save_Click function.

Answer (score 0):

try this...it workd for me....

```
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alertMessage",
"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('value exist');window.location.replace('yourpage.aspx');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we are  showing alert message directly

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"showalert","alert('Only alert Message');",true);
```

Here we are showing alert message from javascript

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "Showalert();", true);
```

These are the two-ways to display alert messages in c#

Comment: update_click is the event for update button click. Its id is btnUpdate

Comment: Based on your requirement you need to use it?,If u write above code on update_click event it will work when ever u click update button only whats wrong in it.where ever you need to display alert messages u use there

Comment: And these is no question it will work with update_click only.It will work at any event(Insert_click or any)

Comment: That was the problem I stated. These methods are only working in the update_click event and not the Save_Click

Comment: Check out your logic in the chkDuplicates function,May be You are wrong with "chkDuplicates" function

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are not using Save button under any **Update Panel**. this problem occurs when you do asynchronous postback. 
I tested your code in new web page and it is working fine.

Code at aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="Save_Click1" />
        <asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" onclick="Update_Click1" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code at Code-Behind file

```
 protected void Save_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int returnId;
        returnId = 1;
        if (returnId == 0)
        { }
        else
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "MsgSave",
                                                "alert('save value exists');", true);
    }
    protected void Update_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int returnId;
        returnId = 2;
        if (returnId == 0)
        { }
        else
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "MsgUpdate",
                                                "alert('update value exists');", true);
    }
```

May be this will help you.